# UPS vs PSU wattage during normal operation?

Tags: power-supply, battery, ups

Does a UPS battery backup act as a "funnel" for wattage during normal power operation (e.g. full power is coming from the wall outlet to the UPS)? I ask because I have an older UPS with only 330W output during a power loss event, and I have a PC with a 750W PSU and a relatively high-power graphics card. If I plug the PC in to the UPS, could damage occur due to not enough power coming from the wall outlet -> UPS -> PSU, even when NOT on battery power?

Comment: Most likely your UPS is of the stand-by type: when the wall socket no longer is providing electrical power, then the battery of the UPS kicks in.  Although your PSU claims to be capable of delivering 750W, it probably cannot unless it is a high-quality unit.  Besides your PC does not constantly consume that much power.  At idle your PC probably consumes about 35-50W, depending on the efficiency of the PSU (which tends to be very inefficient with a small load).  So your PC might have 7 minutes of battery time when main power goes out.  No damage is likely using proper connection as you have.

Comment: The overload will likely cause the UPS to shut down if you lose AC power with the computer operating at high load. This defeats the purpose of the UPS.